# Can't Install npm package, getting weird error

Tags: reactjs, npm, augmented-reality, mindar

[image]

Can't Install mind-ar npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mind-ar

Getting weird error, please help me to resolve

1. I tried with different package that time no error only problem with mind-ar package and i try with different version also nothing solved.
2. https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js#readme here is the code you can verify

error message if you don't want to see the image

```
venkateshk@venkateshs-MacBook-Pro fromCourseStart % npm i mind-ar@1.2.1                                           
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@18.15.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/venkateshk/.npm/_logs/2023-08-12T12_15_37_787Z-debug-0.log
venkateshk@venkateshs-MacBook-Pro fromCourseStart % npm i mind-ar@1.2.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@18.15.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.4 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/venkateshk/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/venkateshk/Desktop/virtual-reality-project/fromCourseStart/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/venkateshk/.npm/_logs/2023-08-12T12_16_48_822Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thank you for let me know it, I will update it

Comment: I tried with a fresh nodejs 16 and it worked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGkXS.png Sometimes 404 error could be related to network issues. Try again in some minutes. Also to validate if is an issue in your machine (a ton of tools), try in another machine or using docker `docker run -it node:16 bash`

Comment: yes sir @JRichardsz
I try with window machine it is working ,but not in mac, thank you let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing carefully your log, the inner exception is: **pkg-config: command not found**

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
```

So, install that tool and try again:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Source: [node-gyp 'pkg-config: command not found' on mac 10.5.8 during npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023316/node-gyp-pkg-config-command-not-found-on-mac-10-5-8-during-npm-install)

If the error changes, research again with the new error. If it is the same, share us in the comments of this answer.

### Advice

- First of all, validate if is an issue in your machine (a ton of tools), try in another machine or using docker `docker run -it node:16 bash`. In some cases the issue is in the library, so there is nothing you can do.
- Review the log line by line looking for error lines
- On each error line, get the most relevant words and search with quotes to have results will only include pages with the same words in the same order as the ones inside the quotes. `"pkg-config: command not found"`